# Is there a way to set up Clap or another arg lib to accept a plain '-' or '+' so that I can obtain argument groups without a named flag?

Tags: rust, arguments, command-line-arguments, clap

I would like to be able to pass arguments using only the - and the + characters in the following format to clap or other arg lib.

```
program -i infile.txt -o outfile.txt - stra strb strc - strd stre strf + strg + strh stri
```

Where in the program I could then obtain vectors with the following groupings...

```
[stra, strb, strc]

[strd, stre, strf]

[strg]

[strh, stri]
```

Is this possible in Clap or another rust arg library?  If so how can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 2):

That is an unusual notation, and I wouldn't expect any library to have an option for it.

Usually `--` stops parsing arguments, so you can have your `-` after this delimiter:

```
program -i infile -- special - separator - args
```

Otherwise you'll need to get `std::env::args().collect::<Vec<_>>()` yourself, and split out or preprocess these args before passing them to Clap.

Comment: Curious what you mean by 'stops parsing arguments'? The double dash is usually an indicator of long form argument... i.e. -v vs. --verbose.  Also, if I'm going to have to end up parsing things myself, is there still a point to using a library?

Comment: `--something` is a long option, `--` is a convention to mean end of options, so the rest is returned as-is (`-` stops being special after `--` argument). I presume a library is still useful to display help pages, parse different variants of the syntax, check required arguments, etc.